# anchor test command error - Error: Cannot find module '[@project-serum/anchor] ' Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry

Tags: javascript, solana-web3js, anchor-solana

I was following an introduction tutorial using anchor (solana framework), it is based in the official github.
In the testing part, I used `anchor test` command and I got this error:

```
BPF SDK: /home/sebastian/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.9.12/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf
cargo-build-bpf child: rustup toolchain list -v
cargo-build-bpf child: cargo +bpf build --target bpfel-unknown-unknown --release
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 3.86s
cargo-build-bpf child: /home/sebastian/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.9.12/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf/dependencies/bpf-tools/llvm/bin/llvm-readelf --dyn-symbols /home/sebastian/Documentos/solana-project/anchor/examples/tutorial/basic-1/target/deploy/basic_1.so

To deploy this program:
  $ solana program deploy /home/sebastian/Documentos/solana-project/anchor/examples/tutorial/basic-1/target/deploy/basic_1.so
The program address will default to this keypair (override with --program-id):
  /home/sebastian/Documentos/solana-project/anchor/examples/tutorial/basic-1/target/deploy/basic_1-keypair.json
yarn run v1.22.17
$ /home/sebastian/Documentos/solana-project/anchor/examples/tutorial/node_modules/.bin/mocha -t 1000000 tests/

Error: Cannot find module '/home/sebastian/Documentos/solana-project/anchor/examples/tutorial/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:353:19)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:566:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sebastian/Documentos/solana-project/anchor/examples/tutorial/basic-1/tests/basic-1.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:170:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:198:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:385:24)
    at async importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:437:15)
    at async formattedImport (/home/sebastian/Documentos/solana-project/anchor/examples/tutorial/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:7:14)
    at async Object.exports.requireOrImport (/home/sebastian/Documentos/solana-project/anchor/examples/tutorial/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:48:32)
    at async Object.exports.loadFilesAsync (/home/sebastian/Documentos/solana-project/anchor/examples/tutorial/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:88:20)
    at async singleRun (/home/sebastian/Documentos/solana-project/anchor/examples/tutorial/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:125:3)
    at async Object.exports.handler (/home/sebastian/Documentos/solana-project/anchor/examples/tutorial/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run.js:374:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "basic-1",
  "version": "0.24.2",
  "license": "(MIT OR Apache-2.0)",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/project-serum/anchor#readme",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/project-serum/anchor/issues"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/project-serum/anchor.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "anchor test --skip-lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@project-serum/anchor": "^0.24.2"
  }
}
```

I really appreciate any information about it. I also attach the tutorial and anchor's github link.

- https://github.com/project-serum/anchor
- https://youtu.be/CmG5_sIas1Q

Answer (score 6):

Try re-installing @project-serum/anchor

`yarn add @project-serum/anchor`

Answer (score 0):

In your anchor.toml file, try changing the value of 'test' to `mocha tests/test.js` , replace test.js with whatever the name of your file in tests.

Comment: Thanks for the information, unfortunately, it throws me the same error. I used `test = "yarn run mocha -t 1000000 tests/basic-1.js"`

Comment: I meant ```test = "mocha tests/basic-1.js```

Answer (score 0):

Go check node_modules/@project-serum/anchor if you don't have a "dist" folder there you will have to run yarn add@project-serum/anchor again. When you can see that the "dist" folder was properly installed you'll be able to run your tests again.